# AWK if number less than previous number, how to add previous number to current number, and from then on

Tags: awk, numeric-data

Have a field with distance data from GoPro. Need to concat the files together but the distance starts at 0 on each new csv file as video files are of only a set duration.

So how would it be possible in the distance field to check when the number is less than the previous record so that it could be added to everything from then on etc., etc?

And if possible how could the time field be incremented from 0 in 0.05 increments?

I have spent a long time reading awk questions on several forums trying to figure this out but haven't managed it, so am finally asking the question myself.

This is the awk one-liner I am using to concat the files and retain one header:

```
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *.csv > all.csv
```

Below you can see how the numbers at the end of one file resets to 0 on each new sheet.

end of csv 1:

```
Time    Feet          Meters        Miles       Kilometers
676.65  9723.24067    2963.643756   1.841523    2.963644
676.7   9723.983124   2963.870056   1.841663    2.96387
676.75  9724.694981   2964.08703    1.841798    2.964087
676.8   9725.429621   2964.310948   1.841937    2.964311
676.85  9726.20625    2964.547665   1.842085    2.964548
676.9   9726.936465   2964.770235   1.842223    2.96477
676.95  9727.547469   2964.956469   1.842339    2.964956
```

start of csv 2:

```
Time    Feet          Meters        Miles       Kilometers
0       0             0             0           0
0.05    0.687379      0.209513      0.00013     0.00021
0.1     1.469281      0.447837      0.000278    0.000448
0.15    2.223126      0.677609      0.000421    0.000678
0.2     2.965581      0.903909      0.000562    0.000904
0.25    3.736514      1.138889      0.000708    0.001139
0.3     4.530231      1.380814      0.000858    0.001381
```

output should be:

```
Time    Feet          Meters        Miles       Kilometers
676.65  9723.24067    2963.643756   1.841523    2.963644
676.7   9723.983124   2963.870056   1.841663    2.96387
676.75  9724.694981   2964.08703    1.841798    2.964087
676.8   9725.429621   2964.310948   1.841937    2.964311
676.85  9726.20625    2964.547665   1.842085    2.964548
676.9   9726.936465   2964.770235   1.842223    2.96477
676.95  9727.547469   2964.956469   1.842339    2.964956
677     9727.547469   2964.956469   1.842339    2.964956
677.05  9728.234848   2965.165982   1.842469    2.965166
677.1   9729.01675    2965.404306   1.842617    2.965404
677.15  9729.770595   2965.634078   1.84276     2.965634
677.2   9730.51305    2965.860378   1.842901    2.96586
677.25  9731.283983   2966.095358   1.843047    2.966095
677.3   9732.0777     2966.337283   1.843197    2.966337
```

Once again would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to U/L! Unfortunately, this questions is currently too vague for us to answer. Please provide sample input and output files.

Comment: Have added a sample.Thanks.

Comment: Have created the three code blocks. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @janeward, much clearer. One other small suggestion: please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/18887). Thanks!

Comment: Have changed the numbers, as Freddy you were right, the numbers I gave were wrong. Apologies. Sincerely. Numbers now right. Removed image on advice of Sparhawk. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution in Python, just in case:

```
import fileinput
from decimal import *

def main():
    save_values = [Decimal(0.0) for n in range(5)]
    last_values = save_values.copy()

    header_shown = False

    for line in fileinput.input():
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "":
            continue
        if line.startswith("Time"):
            if not header_shown:
                print(line)
                header_shown = True
            continue
        (time, feet, meters, miles, kms) = [Decimal(x) for x in line.split()]
        if time == 0.0:
            save_values = last_values.copy()
            continue
        time += save_values[0]
        feet += save_values[1]
        meters += save_values[2]
        miles += save_values[3]
        kms += save_values[4]
        print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(time, feet, meters, miles, kms))
        last_values = [time, feet, meters, miles, kms]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It gives slightly different output, in your output you have:

```
676.95  9727.547469   2964.956469   1.842339    2.964956
677     9727.547469   2964.956469   1.842339    2.964956
```

But I think that right output should be:

```
676.95  9727.547469 2964.956469 1.842339    2.964956
677.00  9728.234848 2965.165982 1.842469    2.965166
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I will try it out shortly.

Comment: Thanks again Fedor. I am a real newbie and cannot get this script to work. I made a file telemetry_concat.py using your code. Added a shebang. Placed in folder with csv files. Made it executable. called if from the terminal by typing python telemetry_concat.py I get the following error: line 34, in <module>
    main()

Comment: @janeward you should list csv files as argument for script, for example: `python telemetry_concat.py all.csv` or `python telemetry_concat.py *.csv` (or post full error if there anything beside KeyboardInterrupt)

Comment: Thanks Fedor. Tried that. Got error again. I must be doing something wrong. Sorry for wasting your time. Error is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telemetry_concat.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "telemetry_concat.py", line 8, in main
    last_values = save_values.copy()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'
Thanks. I understand if you are busy.

Comment: @janeward There are differences in python3 and python2, and this is one them :( I make some changes to work with python2, you could try this file: https://gist.github.com/fedordikarev/38af27f231d1b66dd6a71354a32623b4

Comment: Thanks Fedor. Some good progress. Both versions of your script work with all.csv. Time field works but all other fields return 0s in both versions. It feels as if it is almost there. Really appreciate this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should have posted some example lines and Your current script to get an exact answer.
I would not compare whether number is smaller but save the overall offset when processing the line after adding the offset [0 for first file] and adjust the offset.

Example:
`awk 'FNR==1&&ARGIND>1{distoffset=distnow}{$2+=distoffset;distnow=$2+$3;print $0;}'`

Assuming You have a distance in field 2 and the length of the current entry in field 3 (this needs to be added to distance of previous record I assume otherwise first record of the file had same distance as last record of previous file.

For Your other question I do not understand what You want. Adding 0.05 increments is not problem eigther, but cannot tell You how if I do not understand exact requirement.

---

So with the additional information from Your side I can make my example more complete.
First the more verbose version:

```
rm -f all.csv
awk '
FNR==1 {
 if (ARGIND>1) {
  timeoffset = timenow + 0.05;
  feetoffset = feetnow;
  metersoffset = metersnow;
  milesoffset = milesnow;
  kmeteroffset = kmeternow;
 } else {
  print $0;
 }
 next;
}
FNR>1{
 $1 += timeoffset; timenow = $1;
 $2 += feetoffset; feetnow = $2;
 $3 += metersoffset; metersnow = $3;
 $4 += milesoffset; milesnow = $4;
 $5 += kmeteroffset; kmeternow = $5;
 print $0;
}
' *.csv > all.csv
```

And another one using loops and array instead:

```
rm -f all.csv
awk '
FNR==1 {
 if (ARGIND>1) {
  for (cfn = 1; cfn <= NF; cfn++) {
   offsetvals[cfn] = savedvals[cfn];
  }
  offsetvals[1] += 0.05;
 } else {
  print $0;
 }
 next;
}
FNR>1{
 for (cfn = 1; cfn <= NF; cfn++) {
  $cfn += offsetvals[cfn];
  savedvals[cfn] = $cfn;
 }
 print $0;
}
' *.csv > all.csv
```

And a version with loop which is more generic and can be reused for files where this is not to be applied to all fields or should be made dynamic:

```
rm -f all.csv
awk '
BEGIN {
 procfields["tm"] = 1;
 procfields["ft"] = 2; procfields["mt"] = 3;
 procfields["ml"] = 4; procfields["km"] = 5; 
}
FNR==1 {
 if (ARGIND>1) {
  for (fnname in procfields) {
   cfn = procfields[fnname];
   offsetvals[cfn] = savedvals[cfn];
  };
  offsetvals[procfields["tm"]] += 0.05;
 } else {
  print $0;
 }
 next;
}
FNR>1{
 for (fnname in procfields) {
  cfn = procfields[fnname];
  $cfn += offsetvals[cfn];
  savedvals[cfn] = $cfn;
 };
 print $0;
}
' *.csv > all.csv
```

All assumining the header line You posted is not contained in the files (would be easy to implement, thought).
Second one assuming all fields need processing.

You can omit all the blanks including newlines from AWK script that are not within quoutes (in this case there is not quoted/needed whitespace at all) as You prefer. (Also some semi-coclon could be omitted, but I prefer not to do that.)

Comment: Thanks EOhm for taking the time to write up the different possibilities. Unfortunately they didn't work. The loops froze up my machine. I'm using the BASH shell if that makes a difference. I've edited in the headings in the sample csv files above as they would appear in the real files in case that makes a difference. I tried with and without headings using your examples. Sadly they still didn't work. I'm probably doing something wrong. I really appreciate you took the time to help a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: @janeward did You execute the `rm -f all.csv` before starting the awk`? Then it should loop..
You should be able to just copy&paste one of them when You are in the dir the .csv are in (I took that from Your example).
Which loop You mean freezes?

Comment: I incorporated changes (not include the titles). The other part (putting out title for first file) could also be added. But first You need it working.

Comment: Thanks EOhm. I did delete the all.csv file before running the loops, with and without that rm line. I pasted the awk script into the terminal when it was in the directory of the files. I can see that the variables you're using should work but it doesn't for some reason. Normally I would have the heading kept on the first file and removed from all other files using the awk one-liner: awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *.csv > all.csv Thanks again for your help and your time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh I see something does not work, indeed. I will check.

Comment: OK, the loops are fixed (messed up with writing sometimes cnf instead of cfn [currentfieldnumber]). It's fixed.

Comment: So now they are all three working correctly, only problem is that the original spaces are lost when You change one field contained in $0. So eigther one should implement some formatting (if it should be human readable with fixed size fonts) or one could set for example `$1=$1` before printing out the header to have also the header realigned to be seprated only by OFS instead of original spacing. @janeward

Comment: Because of the other issue @Fedor mentioned.. I had the same thoughts. Eigther some data is lost because not provided in original file (the distance between last line in previous file and the 0 line in next file) - what I assume more, or it is better approach like he did in the python script (do not do the extra increment by 0.05 for time but skip the 0 line in the following files) - which is probably also wrong and causes even more data (the time) to be be inacurate.

Comment: Thanks EOhm. I tried everything again with and without headings. Unfortunately it still does not work. I am using Bash on Linux. Maybe that could be the problem. It is obviously working for you so it seems strange it doesn't work for me. Strange. Anyway, I'd like to thank you for all your effort, time, and help. I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: The current version definitly work in linux bash (and it has almost nothing to do with bash as the most logic is within awk script). I have linux default gawk installed, I assume You have the same. (I just fixed calculation bug in the 3rd one but over all You should have got the results and no hangs if You tried with last versions.)  It's also possible to put all the stuff between the single quotes into an script file (ex. conect.awk) and call it like `awk -f concat.awk *.csv > all.csv` to be sure it has nothing to do with Your shell environment.

Comment: Thanks again EOhm. Tried all 3 scripts as script files. First one returns correct time but 0s in all other fields. Second script returned just the time which is correct. Third script returns time which is correct and 0s for all other fields. Maybe there really is something wrong with my terminal. I'm sure you're right it should work. Strange. Thanks for all your help. And your time. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm yes I see You have same problem with Python script. I think Python is much more powerful but for simple tasks like ad-hoc file or output filtering it's very good.  I assume you have some strange input files. So our scripts don't do the splitting as expected.. maybe you should do a hexdump -C on one of the files to check